# How to group all similar Strings separately in an ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, similarity

I have an `ArrayList` of Strings which would be having a size `1,000 to 30,000` elements.

```
    ArrayList<String> name= new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> similar_group =new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<munber;i++)
    {
    name.Add("name");
    }
```

I want to group the similar Strings and put them to an `ArrayList`.

For eg there are `10` elements in the `name ArrayList` with value "a" then all the elements whose value is equal to "a" should be added to an `ArrayList` and then that `ArrayList` should be added to `similar_group` `ArrayList`.

If there is any element in `name` `ArrayList` whose value is unique then even that should be added to a `ArrayList` and then that `ArrayList`  should be added to `similar_group` ArrayList.

The size of the ArrayList may be big. So is there any way to the do this?

Comment: Easy, two inner fors can solve your problem, get one element from the list and compare it to the rest of the list, removing the equals elements and adding to the other one. Since it looks like homework we cant post code, but if you achieve to develop something we can help continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    package application;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class T {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "B");
            Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            list.forEach(ele->{
                List<String> innerList= new ArrayList<>();
                if(map.containsKey(ele)){
                    innerList = map.get(ele);
                }
                innerList.add(ele);
                map.put(ele, innerList);
            });
            List<List<String>> valueList = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
            System.out.println(valueList);
        }
    }
```

By adding each unique element to a list like this

o/p : [[A], [B, B], [C], [D]]

### Refactored code :

```
    package application;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class T {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "B");
            HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            List<List<String>> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
            list.stream().forEach(ele -> {
                List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (map.containsKey(ele)) {
                    innerList = map.get(ele);
                } else {
                    valueList.add(innerList);
                }
                innerList.add(ele);
                map.put(ele, innerList);
            });
            System.out.println(valueList);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer did not work exactly for me but the logic did help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove duplicates from an `ArrayList` you should consider whether you actually need to use a `List` (which allows duplicates) instead of a `Set` (which doesn't allow duplicates). The only caveat here is that a `Set` is unordered, but this can be changed by using a `LinkedHashSet`.
If you need it to stay as a `ArrayList`, try adding everything in the `ArrayList` to a `HashSet` and back to an `ArrayList` to remove duplicates (this does **not** preserve the order of elements):

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
s.addAll(a);
a.clear();
a.addAll(s);
```

Comment: Thanks You for the answer. But I don't want to remove duplicates but instead find the duplicates present in that `ArrayList`.